# Eclipse - Undo "Convert to JavaScript Project..."

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse

I am working on a AngularJS/Gradle project within Eclipse.
Everything was working fine and no error was displayed within my project explorer.

Due to an idea I chose my project -> right click -> Configure -> Convert to JavaScript project...

After that I had various errors in my *.js (AngularJS) files in my project explorer (but my project works fine!). Therefore I decided to remove the nature from my ".project" file but the errors are still there.

What's the correct way to "undo" that "Convert to JavaScript project" stuff?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to remove errors from the Problem View? It's out of scope, but I suggest you that you install https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: Removing errors doesn't fix my problem, the errors are appearing again after a while. (Out of scope: I know about AngularJS-Eclipse...)

Answer (score 4):

I think It doesn't exists a **Un-convert to JavaScript Project**. So you must edit your **.project** and remove the following lines:

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
</natures>
```

After go at to your **Problems View** and remove the error if it exists again.

Comment: +1 for the tip to manually remove the error once the nature and the builder are removed from the .project